# Passing Creds - New-PSSession

Tags: powershell, scripting, exchange-server, credentials

I am trying to connect to exchange via the following

```
 $Cred = Get-StoredCredential "User"


 Function Connect-OnPremExchange {
 
    $ExOPSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://server101/PowerShell/ -Credential $Cred
 
    Import-PSSession $ExOPSession -AllowClobber
 }
```

However, I'm still getting prompted for a username/password. I don't want to hardcode it into the script and need to use the creds in my credential manager. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your credential manger may not be storing your credentials in a way that PowerShell can read. Have you tried storing your credentials in an encrypted xml file? You can at least test them this way.

Example:

Step 1 - outside of script

```
    Get-Credential | Export-Clixml -Path "C:\temp\creds.xml"
```

Step 2 - inside script

```
    $creds = import-clixml -path "c:\temp\creds.xml"
```

Comment: I'm trying not to store them any place other than the credentials manager. I have other scripts calling this without issue. The problem is, when I attempt to create a New-PSSession and connect to Exchange it prompts me even though I'm passing credentials. I'm trying to figure out a way around this.

Comment: Are your other scripts calling a new-pssession?  Or are they passing the credentials straight to a client?  What properties does your $cred object have?  Is the password stored as a System.Security.SecureString object?